# @Scheduled being called at server startup

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jboss, spring-scheduled

We are using JBoss App server 7.0.0, Spring 4.1.6 , Hibernate-JPA 2.0 in our project. I want to persist data at configured interval specified in the properties. For this i am using spring scheduling 
`@Scheduled(fixedRateString = "${db.commit.interval}")`,
`public void commitToDB()`
But one problem i am facing is this method is called automatically on server startup meaning if i scheduled this method to be called every 5th minute , i expect that after server startup at 12:00:00 this method should be called at 12:00:05 but it is being called at 12:00:00 only (i.e **on server startup)**. Can any one suggest is it a problem or am i missing something ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add a `initialDelayString` property.

Also, give it the same value as your fixed rate.

However, if what you want is to have it running **exactly** at the fifth minute of an hour, the tenth minute and so on, consider using a `cron` expression in your annotation .

Comment: @ Berger :Thanks i have used previously it works fine with initialDelay it works but actaully i wanted to understand does it fire at first invocation and then calcualte the count for subsequent hits.

Comment: As you are only specifying an interval, nothing tells the scheduler when to start, so I guess it starts the first execution as soon as possible, which is just after server startup .

Comment: @ Berger : yes i think it can be a probable reason, but i did not find anything related in documentation.